# Finding the length with respect to x

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

This is a "simple" geometrry/trigonometry problem that I need for a physics problem and it is driving me insane because I can't figure it out.

I have some particle that is moving along the x-axis and I want to find a function or expression for $\vec{r}(x)$. So basically I want to find how the hypotenuse changes with respect to x.

I have the initial conditions $x=ab$ when the particle is at $x_0$

Does this even have a simple solution?

Comment: Pythagoras? I'm not sure what else to suggest without more information.

Comment: @Chappers Yeah I already thought of that. This is actually part of a problem that I asked on physics stackexchange. Maybe this helps: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/182657/question-about-particles-in-electric-fields-homework-question

Comment: I don't think you've distinguished clearly enough between the value of $x$ when $t=0$ and the value of $x$ at general $t$. If you do that, it's clearer what things should be when you draw the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec{r}(x) = -x\vec{i} + \frac{ab}{2}\vec{j}$ because your $\vec{r}(x)$ is a vector.

Then $\left|\vec{r}(x)\right| = \sqrt{x^2 + \left(\frac{ab}{2}\right)^2}$ by Pythagoras's theorem

Comment: Thanks or your help. I figured it out.